# Powershell For Each Variable By Number

Tags: powershell, shell, loops, foreach, command-line

I have the following variables:

```
$testvar_1 = 1, 100
$testvar_2 = 1, 20
$testvar_3 = 0, 260
$testvar_4 = 1, 10
```

How can I make a for loop that will loop through each variable array?

*** When you dont know the total number of $testvar_n variables and it changes constantly. ***

Something like `For Each $testvar_n do { $testvar_n[1] = $testvar_n[1] + 10 }`

Sorry very new to powershell.

EDIT:

Perhaps something that can work like the below?

`get-variable testvar* | ForEach-Object -Process {$_[1]+10}`

Comment: perhaps it would be useful to back up a few steps? what is giving you those mini-arrays? can that process be modified to give you one array?

Comment: Perhaps I could convert it, but I am receiving the data like that from an outside source. I am trying to make it work but getting quite stuck on this.

Comment: ah! well, it looks like `AdminOfThings` has a solution for you. good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: Both of your help is much appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the following if you need to actually update the existing variables.

```
foreach ($var in (Get-Variable -Name testvar_[0-9]* -ValueOnly)) {
    $var[1] += 10
}
```

**Note:** `[0-9]` is the wildcard range operator for any single digit. The wildcard character `*` matches zero or more characters, which could match `testvar_1abc` for example. You can further prevent that with a `Where-Object` condition if necessary. See below for further filtering.

```
$vars = Get-Variable -Name testvar_[0-9]* | Where Name -match '^testvar_\d+$'
foreach ($var in $vars) {
        $var.Value[1] += 10
}
```